# How to map info from .json after using hook and promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `data.json` file like this:

```json
"valid": true,
  "timestamp": 1582195447,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.67338,
    "AFN": 77.8079
}
```

I am simulating receiving data from the backend in this way.

```js
import data from './data.json';

function App1(){
    const promise = new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) =>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log('Preparing...');
                resolve(data)
            }, 2000)
        }
    )
    promise.then(clientData =>{
        console.log('Promise resolved', clientData);
        
    })
    
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                 
            </ul>
              
        </div>
    )
}
```

I also tried to do it like this:

```js
import data from './data.json';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App1(){
    const [state, setState] = useState('');
    const promise = new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) =>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                setState(data);
                resolve(state);
            }, 2000)
        }
    )
    promise.then(clientData =>{
        console.log('Promise resolved', clientData);
        let newArr = clientData.toA
        setState(clientData);
        
    })
    
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {state ? state.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li> ) : 'Loading data...'} 
            </ul>
              
        </div>
    )
}

export default App1;
```

But this throws `TypeError: state.map is not a function`.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is a lot of questions: What happens if you `console.log(data)`? where do you get name and id from? Are you aware of React hooks? Try to search for useEffect()

Comment: @PixAff `{valid: true, timestamp: 1582195447, base: "USD", rates: {…}}
base: "USD"
rates: {AED: 3.67338, AFN: 77.8079, ALL: 113.23065, AMD: 478.14251, ANG: 1.78845, …}
timestamp: 1582195447
valid: true
__proto__: Object` it is `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Promises are asynchronous. There's a short span of time when your component exists and React tries to render it, but the data from the server hasn't arrived yet. During that time, your `state` still hasn't been populated by the response from the server, and still has the default value, which you've set to an empty string with `useState('')`. Strings do not have a `map` method, hence you get the error "state.map" is not a function -- it's `undefined`. Try `''.map` in the console to see this.

The quickest fix is to use `useState([])`.

Another possibility is to use `useState(null)` for the beginning and then display a loading indicator to the user while `state` is `null`.

Comment: sorry, i didnt note that I need to display all the information not in the console, i must dislay it on the web-page, tell me please how to do this (with this delay, as in the console)  need to display it in a list or in a table. Also i tried you solution but it did not help me, unfortunately

Comment: There is a delay in the console as well, you just don't see it. Learn about promises and how they work. My solution is not for console (not sure where did you get that from).

Comment: i mean that i want to see the delay on my web page (2000ms). Error is the same `state.map is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate getting data from an api you should do it inside of a hook:

```
    import data from './data.json';
import {useEffect, useState} from "React"
    
    function App1(){
const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
         async function getDatafromApi() {
           const res = await // your api call (returns data)
           setMyData(data) // in your case since you have no api
           // setMyData(res) This is what you would do if you had an api
         }
         getDataFromApi();
},[myData])
        
        
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                     
                </ul>
                  
            </div>
        )
    }

export default App1
```

But still - if your data does not contain `name` or `id` it will not work!